# Determining the residue of a function by computing its laurent expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I need to find the residue of $$f(z) = \frac{e^z\sin(z)}{z(1-\cos(z))}$$ at $z = 0$ via its Laurent series expansion. First of all, I tried to expand all the functions via Taylor series at $z = 0$.
I obtained, after some easy computations, the following expression:
$$\frac{2}{z^2}\cdot \frac{1+z+\frac{z^2}{3}+\dots}{1-\frac{z^2}{12}+\dots }$$
Now, my idea was to somehow simplify the denominator, by multiplicating and dividing by some factor, and get an expression of this form:
$\frac{2}{z^2} (1+z+\frac{z^2}{3}+\dots)(?\dots ?)$.
I failed and couldn't find a way to put the above expression in the usual form of a Laurent series, namely: $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}c_nz^n$ since I only need the $c_{-1}$ coefficient in order to determine the residue
If someone could give me a hand, I'd gladly appreciate it.

Comment: You know how to find the coefficient for $z^{-1}$ term, right?  and you are asking for some further work to get a more friendly form?

Comment: Well, as I said, I gotta get rid of that denominator first, so that I can "isolate" it, but I can't seem to find a way right now. It might be simpler than I think, but I just can't see how at the moment

Comment: If you only need to find the coefficient for $z^{-1}$ term, you don't need to get rid of the denominator.

Comment: Wait, how can you see it without getting rid of it? Am I missing something?

Comment: I found a way: it was much easier than I thought. I need to find a new power series such that $S_{n_1} * S_{n_2} = 1$. This can obviously be done if the constant term isn't zero

Comment: Wait could you explain it a bit further, I've just been introduced to Laurent series, therefore I lack most of the proficiency required. My professor usually does what I did when we have a function presenting sin, exp, cos, whose Taylor expansion is well known

Comment: Yes, I wrote a solution, hope it helps.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The first terms for $z\sin z$ are $$e^z\sin z=z+z^2+\frac{z^3}{3}-\frac{z^5}{30}-\frac{z^6}{90}+O(z^7)+\cdots,$$ and the first terms for $$1-\cos z=-\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^4}{4!}+\frac{z^6}{6!}+\cdots.$$ Since the pole at $z=0$ of $\frac{1}{1-\cos z}$ has order $2$ we know that the laurent series is on the form $\sum_{n=-2}^\infty a_n z^n,$ with the odd terms equal to zero, so $$\left(-\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^4}{4!}+\frac{z^6}{6!}+\cdots\right)\left(a_{-2}z^{-2}+a_0+a_2z^2+\cdots\right)=1,$$ it's easy to compute the first terms, where you obtain that $$\frac{1}{1-\cos z}=\frac{2}{z^2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{z^2}{120}+\cdots.$$ Now we have that $$\frac{1}{z}\frac{e^z\sin z}{1-\cos z}=\left(1+z+\frac{z^2}{3}+\cdots\right)\left(\frac{2}{z^2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{z^2}{120}+\cdots\right)=\frac{2}{z^2}+\frac{2}{z}+\frac{5}{6}+\frac{z}{6}+\cdots,$$ so the residue is $2$.

Comment: Im sick to death of this website. Can anyone  explain me the downvotes? Ridiculous

Comment: Firstly, thank you. Secondly, you basically computed the Laurent series of the function in the numerator (which has no principal part), and that of the denominator. You found the latter by basically saying: I consider $f(x)$. I can express $1-cosz$ via power series. The power series tells me that the function  has a second order zero, so its inverse has a 2nd oder pole there. Then you basically multiplied $\frac{1}{f(x} f(x)$ expressed via power series and found the coefficients by comparison. But how do you know it starts from the $c_{-2}$ term a priori?

Comment: Because the pole of $1/(1-\cos z) $ has order two.

Comment: Therefore, more generally, the strategy to use when I need to find the Laurent expansion of $1 / f(z)$ at, for instance, $z_0$, is determining the zeros of $f(x)$ so that I can easily find the order of the coefficient  $c_{-n}$ from which the Laurent series will start, namely the order of the pole of $1 / f(z)$ at $z_0$

Comment: Exactly, that's the idea of my answer :)

Comment: I'm new to the forum, in fact, it's my first time here. I'm sorry the site downvoted you Guillermo . I upvoted and accepted your answer if that can help :)

Comment: I wasnt upset about not having the answer accepted, but I Know many people downvote just for Envy, that's sad. Hope I helped you, Also @MathFail answer is a good one.

Comment: Yes I upvoted @MathFail answer as well

Comment: I am not downvoting. I don't have enough reputation to downvote :) But I guess people downvote because this method is redundant and maybe mislead the author or other audiences. This method is correct, but no need to be so redundant. It is like to compute $37\cdot 10$, by using multiplication it immediately gives $370$, so there is no need to do the redundant way, such as to add them $37+37+\dots+37=370$.

Answer (score 2):

First we simplify it

$$f(z) = \frac{e^z\sin(z)}{z(1-\cos(z))}=\frac{e^z\cdot2\sin(\frac z2)\cos(\frac z2)}{z\cdot2\sin^2(\frac z2)}=\frac{e^z\cdot\cos(\frac z2)}{z\cdot\sin(\frac z2)}$$

We can see, $z=0$ is a second order pole from above result. Then by residue formula

$$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{d}{dz}z^2f(z)=2$$

Or, if you want to do the Laurent series and find the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ term, you can do the following,

$$\frac{e^z\cdot\cos(\frac z2)}{z\cdot\sin(\frac z2)}\sim\frac{1}{z\cdot \frac z2}\cdot \left(1+z+O(z^2)\right)\cdot\left(1+O(z^2)\right)$$

Since we only need the  $z^{-1}$ term, hence

$$\frac{1}{z\cdot \frac z2}\cdot z=2\cdot\frac1z$$

the coefficient is $2$, which agrees with above result by applying residue formula.

Comment: This was my intent, you cleverly got rid of all the unnecessary terms, which I did not. Thank you for the answer.